# How to start new activity on BroadcastReceiver when I click on button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to make application, that can extends "BroadcastReceiver", and on the xml GUI there is a button, I am trying to open new Activity(GUI) when I press on it. I know how to do it when I extends Activity, but not when I extends BroadcastReceiver. this is my java code:

```
import info.kfsoft.android.R.raw;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    TextView display;


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music2);


        Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage [] messages = null;
        String strMessage = "";

        if (myBundle != null)
        {
            Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
            {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
               strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();                  
           }            
            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);            
            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
            ourSong.start();           
        }
    }
    public void a(){

    }

}
```

and this is my xml RelativeLayout that works with the previous java code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="info.kfsoft.android.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

NOW I want to open new intent when I press the button (WITH @+ID/CMD):

This is the Jave code of the new intent:

```
public class AboutUs extends Activity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.about);
        }

    }
```

Comment: you wana start activity from reciver?

Comment: I don´t know waht You are trying to do, because You can set no view to a broadcast receiver. Are You acting from another activity where You start the BroadcastReceiver or do You work with RemoteViews??

Comment: @Selvin I am trying to open new Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Answer is, You can start an Activity from Receiver like this:

```
     Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AboutUs.class);        
     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(i);
```

This is how You are starting an Activity from Receiver. But You have to send broadcast from another activity first to "wake up" Your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I tried to use it, but I can't use the button. Do you know how to use it when I press on the button. thx

Comment: I really don´t know what You are trying, sorry. So what I guess is, that You are making a widget? Could it be? I think we need to see more of Your code and the important thing is...where is Your button? I mean, in which Activity or AppwidgetProvider do You use this RelativeLayout?

Comment: I use the fragment_main.xml to the button and also I have activity_main.xml which is blank.

Comment: your code worked(its started new activity), but do you know how to use the button. thxxxx

Comment: is the RelativeLayout the R.layout.about ?

Answer (score 0):

On button click

```
 OnClickListener listnr=new OnClickListener() {

                  @Override

                  public void onClick(View v) {

  Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);        

     context.startActivity(i);



                  }

            };

            Button btn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

            btn.setOnClickListener(listnr);
```